# Heroku: command not found windows 7

Tags: heroku

I've installed the heroku cli on Win7.

I've created a small python application. I've run git add and commit. I then run git heroku commit master but get a "Heroku: command not found" error.

heroku shows in my Path and is under C:\Program Files\Heroku

how can I push this up to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Add environment variable in system variable `path` including bin.

```
 C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
```

and restart the cmd/git console.

Hope this helps.